# Python List Comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having difficulty with a homework assignment. I am trying to determine whether a list of words is contained in a list of characters.

For example:

```
([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], ['ANT', 'BOX', 'SOB', 'TO'])
```

I am trying to determine how many times the list of words is in the other two lists. (It should return 3)('ANT', "SOB', and 'TO')

The first lists will end up being displayed like this:(Yes it reads words in both columns and rows)

```
ANTT
XSOB
```

There will later be more than two lists.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Convert all of the words to `set`s and just compare them. `set('hello') == set('elho')`

Comment: this would miss anything that had duplicate letters ...

Comment: The OP needs to check what words are in rows and columns of a table; I don't see how making sets and losing the order would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate strings from rows and columns:

```
In [1]: data = ([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], ['ANT', 'BOX', 'SOB', 'TO'])

In [2]: rows = [''.join(s) for s in data[0]]

In [3]: rows
Out[3]: ['ANTT', 'XSOB']

In [4]: cols = [''.join(s) for s in zip(*data[0])]

In [5]: cols
Out[5]: ['AX', 'NS', 'TO', 'TB']
```

Then check what words are in those strings:

```
In [6]: for word in data[1]:
    if any(word in s for s in rows+cols):
        print word # you can increment your counter here as well
   ...:         
ANT
SOB
TO
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a homework assignment let me explain what must occur. In your code above you have a list of lists if my Python is correct.  So the first thing you have to do is construct the words that you are looking for based on the lists that are single characters.  For instance your list of ['A','N','T'] would need to produce a word of `ANT`.  Now once you have the words you are looking for you must check the completed word list.  In your example above that would be the final list element.  So you take your `newWords` list and iterate over it seeing if it is contained by the last element of the `originalList`.  If it is found increment the `foundWords` counter by 1.

Answer (score 0):

something like this: using  `all()`.

```
In [73]: lis1
Out[73]: [['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]

In [74]: lis2
Out[74]: ['ANT', 'BOX', 'SOB', 'TO']

In [75]: [x for x in lis2 if (any(x in "".join(y) for y in lis1) or any(x in "".join(k) for k in zip(*lis1)))]
Out[75]: ['ANT', 'SOB', 'TO']
```

Comment: it being homework, doesn't that seem a bit advanced?

Comment: I don't think it answers the OP's question.

Comment: @LevLevitsky you're right, I misread the question. updated my solution.